# Laravel ajax my column id is not being shown by console.log

Tags: sql, ajax, laravel, model, controller

Demonstration on how my `catagory_id` is being read (console.log each time I press the edit button)

[image: 1]

```
        $(document).on('click','.edit_category',function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var cat_id = $(this).val();
            console.log(cat_id);
        });
```

My problem is when I try to output the an array shown at the consoles by clicking the edit button (testing purposes)

[image: 2]

Not sure how I still get the 404 as the `category_id` is already defined in the table

blade:

```
<td>
<button type="button" value="${cat.category_id}" class="edit_category btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
<button type="button" value="${cat.category_id}" class="delete_category btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>
</td>
```

ajax:

```
    $(document).on('click','.edit_category',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var cat_id = $(this).val();
        // console.log(cat_id);
        $('#editCategoryModal').modal('show');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/bbr-category-configuration-edit/"+cat_id,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
```

controller:

```
public function edit($category_id) {
    $category_edit = HmsBbrCategory::find($category_id);
    if ($category_edit) 
    {
        return response()->json([
            'status'=>200,
            'status'=>$category_edit,
        ]);
    }
    else
    {
        return response()->json([
            'status'=>404,
            'status'=>'Category Not Found',
        ]);
    }
}
```

model:

```
public $timestamps = false;
protected $table = 'hms_bbr_category';
```

route:

```
    Route::get('/bbr-category-configuration', [BBRCategoryConfigurationController::class,'index']);
    Route::get('/bbr-category-configuration-data', [BBRCategoryConfigurationController::class,'fetchcategory']);
    Route::post('/bbr-category-configuration', [BBRCategoryConfigurationController::class,'store']);
    Route::get('/bbr-category-configuration-edit/{category_id}', [BBRCategoryConfigurationController::class,'edit']);
```

[image: 3]

any advice or input would be appreciated, thankyou

Comment: can you show all routes from web.php

Comment: what happens if you hit /bbr-category-configuration-edit/3 directly in your browser?  it looks like your if ($category_edit) {} isn't false so its returning 404

Comment: allroutes added @JohnLobo

Comment: @Cameron you suggestion shows the full  array `{"status":{"id":1,"category_id":1,"category_name":"General","category_description":"Public Category accessible by all","effective_start_datetime":"2014-01-01 00:00:00","effective_end_datetime":null,"created_by":"ktphadmin@ktph.com.sg","created_datetime":"2014-01-01 00:00:00","archived_by":null,"archived_datetime":null,"config_view_type":"P","config_edit_type":"P","bbrmode_view_type":"P","delete_flag":0}}`

Comment: what about changing value="${cat.category_id}" to value="{{$cat.category_id}}"